# Removing a JPanel from a JFrame from a different class(and adding a new one)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Ok guys, need a bit of help with this. So, I'm busy writing a game in Java, using a main menu to go to different sub-games(each of which has its own class), but I ran into this problem:

I have a main JFrame, which (in theory) each sub-game (and the main menu) add different JPanels too, and obviously remove the previous one.

This is the code for the main menu(mainp is the JPanel):
    frame.add(mainp);

```
    mainp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    getContentPane().add(mainp);
    GridBagLayout lay = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();
    Game.mainp.setLayout(lay);

    cons.weightx = 0.5;
    cons.gridx = 0;
    cons.gridy = 0;
    Game.mainp.add(ringsb, cons);
    cons.weightx = 0.5;
    cons.gridx = 0;
    cons.gridy = 1;
    Game.mainp.add(xob, cons);
```

All good so far(ringsb and xob are buttons), but then when I run this code(from a different class(and file)):

```
ringsp.setLayout(lay);
    cons.weightx = 0.5;
    cons.gridx = 0;
    cons.gridy = 0;
    ringsp.add(Item1, cons);
    cons.weightx = 0.5;
    cons.gridx = 0;
    cons.gridy = 1;
    ringsp.add(Item2, cons);
    cons.weightx = 0.5;
    cons.gridx = 0;
    cons.gridy = 2;
    ringsp.add(Item3, cons);
    Game.frame.remove(Game.mainp);
    Game.frame.add(ringsp);
```

I don't get any errors, it just doesn't do what it should :(  (Game was the name of the other class).

Any help??

Answer (score 4):

> I have a main JFrame, which (in theory) each sub-game (and the main menu) add different JPanels too, and obviously remove the previous one.

You should be using a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for this. It will allow you to swap panels easily.

Comment: Ok, thanks, will try that. Be back to say if it worked.

Comment: It didn't work :( I'll ask a new question and post a link just now.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770412/cardlayout-panels-not-changing)  Thanks in advance for help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean in your question. But basically you are saying that the second panel does not show. You only still see the first panel right?

The frame should be validated after you add or remove panels to it :

```
Game.frame.validate();
```

This will redraw the GUI layout.